# Parsing issue in a lexer file

Tags: parsing, antlr4, lexer

I have the following line in my lexer:

```
LITERAL_STRING  
    : '"' .*? '"' ( ('@' LETTER+) | ('^^' HTML_STRING))?
    ;
```

While parsing a string, Lexer only obtains some parts of the string.

For example: here is the example of one of the string literals: `"Manuel Ben\u00EDtez \"El Cordob\u00E9s\""@es`. I want to get the entire string but it only gets this :`"Manuel Ben\u00EDtez \"`.

How can I have the entire string clearly (in this case :`"Manuel Ben\u00EDtez \"El Cordob\u00E9s\""@es`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `.*?`, do `( ~[\\"] | \\ . )*`:

```
LITERAL_STRING  
    : '"' ( ~[\\"] | \\ . )* '"' ( ('@' LETTER+) | ('^^' HTML_STRING))?
    ;
```

Explanation:

```
~[\\"]       # any char other than a backslash and double quote
|            # OR 
\\ .         # a backslash followed by any char
```